# Component scan: Load bean with Spring

Tags: spring

I have a little question about Spring component scan.

I would like to load all beans in my "my.package.test" and one bean in "my.package".
To do this, I wrote this xml:

```
<context:component-scan
    base-package="my.package.test" use-default-filters="false" >
    <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
    <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Service"/>
    <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Component"/>
    <context:include-filter type="assignable" expression="my.package.TestBean" />   
</context:component-scan>
```

All my beans in "my.package.test" are well loaded but my TestBean is not load, I have the no matching bean error.
My TestBean is well annoted @Component.

I don't understand why it's not loaded.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

In your example TestBean is in the "my.package" package but Spring is scanning everything under "my.package.test".  It's unclear if this is just an anonymization issue but that would cause your bean to not be found.

Comment: Yes Spring scans all under "my.package.test" but I have several beans in "my.package" and I want it to scan just one, the TestBean. I believed this line allowed that:     <context:include-filter type="assignable" expression="my.package.TestBean" />    because I declare one bean explicitly

Comment: If you just want one bean loaded just define it as a bean rather than scanning for it:  '<bean class="my.package.TestBean" />'.  Component scan is for automatically scanning packages and creating beans.

Comment: Yes, I know I can do this but what is the aim of this tag (context:include-filter type="assignable") if it's not to create a specific bean ?

Comment: It's to create a specific bean only when you'vedisabled the default filters (which you've done).  However you set the base-package to scan to a package which doesn't include your TestBean.  Thus you need to either change the base-package for the component scanner to "my.package" or define your bean explicitly.